# What is a few good abstract algebra books for second courses

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

What is a few good abstract algebra books for second courses that is both readable for advanced undergraduate and beginning graduate student?

Or the intermediate one for self study?

Or at the same level as Herstein's Topics in algebra?

Comment: It's not clear what "a second course" means.  Do you mean an honors level undergraduate course?  A graduate level course?

Comment: beginning graduate level?

Comment: After Herstein I went on to Hungerford's graduate textbook.

Comment: What did you study in the first course? What is the purpose of continuing?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Just for self study and i used Frelaigh as my first textbook in college

Comment: Even self-study has a *purpose*. @Victor

Comment: We use Dummit and Foote in our graduate class. Very detailed and encompassing.

Comment: Dummit and Foote is an excellent text. I don't know if it is at a really upper level, but I can recommend it without hesitating.